# Whats the consistency strength of this theory?

Tags: first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

Language: First order logic with identity and extra-logical primitives of membership $``\in"$, and $``W"$, the last is a constant symbol.

**Axioms:** *ID* axioms +

1.**Extensionality:** $\forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$

*Define:* $set(y) \iff \exists x (y \in x)$

2.**Class comprehension:** if $\varphi$ is a formula in which $x$ is not free, then all closures of:

$$\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \varphi \wedge set(y))$$; are axioms.

3.**Reflection:** for n=0,1,2,3,...; if $\varphi$ is a formula in the pure language of set theory (i.e., doesn't use the symbol $``W"$), that has all of its free variables among symbols $``y,x_1,..,x_n"$; then:

$x_1,..,x_n \in W \to [\forall y (\varphi \to y \subseteq W) \to \forall y (\varphi \to y \in W)]$,

is an axiom.

4.**Transitivity:** $x \in W \to x \subset W$

/ Theory definition finished.

This axiomatic system is amongst the simplest ones proposed for set theory. It look even simpler than the axioms for ZFC.

Yet I think this theory is much stronger than ZFC.

> What's the exact consistency strength of this system?

It would be tempting to add the following axiom:

5. **Limitation of size:** $x \subset W \wedge |x| < |W| \to x \in W$.

I think this would further increase the strength of this theory.

Also a further note about this theory is that I think it doesn't really need Extensionality, i.e. this theory minus Extensionality can interpret it with Extensionality. Moreover, I think also that axiom of Transitivity, can be dispensed with, since we can interpret it over the class of all sets that are hereditarily elements of $W$. So what is really needed is only Class Comprehension and Reflection.

Comment: Since the term reflection is a very well-used term with a very concrete meaning, could you explain how your use adheres to that meaning?

Comment: Also, note that extensionality + comprehension is an even simpler theory, and its consistency strength is far stronger than ZFC, it is so strong it can prove 0=1.

Comment: you mean "naive comprehension", but I think this theory does have a model assuming some large cardinal properties.

Comment: here we are reflecting set properties from subsets of $W$ to the inside of $W$, so it is a kind of reflection.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. In Axiom 2, let $\varphi$ be $y\not \in y.$  Then $set(x)$ because  $[\neg set (x)]\implies \forall z\;(x\not \in z)\implies x\not \in x \implies x\in x$ (by Axiom 2)$\implies set (x)$.... So $x$ is the set of all sets that are not members of themselves.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, if you let $\varphi$ be $y \not \in y$ you get x being the class of all sets that are not element of themselves. Yes, but x itself is not a set, it would be a proper class. No contradiction.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet your line of thought is wrong! your error is at the implication $x \not \in x \implies x \in x$. In order for any object y by axiom 2 to be an element of x,  y must be a set and fulfill $\varphi$; fulfilling $\varphi$ alone is not enough for y to be an element of x by axiom 2.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, axiom 2. is well known. See Morse-Kelley set theory.